# Is WindowsAzure implemented in Xamarin's all platforms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

We are using **DownloadToByteArrayAsync** function in Xamarin portable project, it is running fine in Windows.UWP project, but we are getting error in iOS & Android. projects.

Error details:
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: An error occurred while sending the request ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request ---> System.Net.WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused)

Comment: It's implemented, for some reason your connection is refused. Is the date and time correct on the device?

Comment: @GeraldVersluis: Yes, date & time are correct. Internet is also working as we are able to access the Blob from device's web browser.

Comment: For iOS and Android projects, you need to tune the manifest files to enable internet connection related permissions. Have you done that?

Answer (score 0):

I've added 2 references to all projects:

```
NETStandard.Library

System.Net.Http
```

packages.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
<package id="NETStandard.Library" version="1.6.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
<package id="System.Net.Http" version="4.3.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
</packages>
```

Comment: Unable to install System.Net.Http through nuGet, getting error that it is not compatible with with the framework.